# SphinxQL: How to SUM() custom field with GROUP BY or RANK results by custom field

Tags: php, sum, aggregate, sphinx, sphinxql

I have an index with next structure:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| id | entity_id | content | weight_field |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 1  | 1         | car     | 1.2          |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 2  | 1         | desert  | 1.45         |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 3  | 1         | water   | 1.55         |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 4  | 2         | water   | 1.1          |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 5  | 2         | desert  | 1.9          |
+----+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

Could somebody tell me if possible to `SUM()` field values with grouping?
I tried this

```sql
SELECT SUM(weight_field) AS sort, entity_id FROM test_index WHERE MATCH ('@content car|desert|water') GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY sort DESC
```

But got error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end near '()'
```

I expected to get next result:

```
+------+-----------+
| sort | entity_id |
+------+-----------+
| 4.2  | 1         |
+------+-----------+
| 3.0  | 2         |
+------+-----------+
```

The second way good for me:
Use custom `weight_field` (which contain float values as `1.563`, `1.02` and etc) to rank results. But I not sure that it possible to do with

```
OPTION ranker=...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finnaly find the reason:

In real code, not in example, I named `weight_field` as `weight`. So sphinx recognized it as predefined FUNCTION `WEIGHT()` and throw error which tells that it wants see `()` after `weight`.

After fixing it and re-indexing it works.

Comment: ah yes WEIGHT will effectively be reserved word.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to use `weight` as alias

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
SELECT SUM(WEIGHT()) AS sort,...
```

should work. Where is `WEIGHT()` is the value as computed by the current ranker.

Comment: Yes, may be you're right. But is it possible to set my own field `weight_field` as result for WEIGHT()?